# regex code doesn't work on single line mode

Tags: python, regex

I have a single-line string in python and need to extract texts from it.
[screenshot from regex101](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdbSI.png)

I need to find any lines ending with a dot after a [ROB#].

The code in the screenshot `(\[ROB\d*])\s*\n\s*(.*?[\.\:]\s*\n)` only find the first line.
When I add a `+` after that like `(\[ROB\d*])\s*\n\s*(.*?[\.\:]\s*\n)+` and change the mode to multiline mode. then it gets working fine.
But the regex code with a plus sign doesn't work as expected on single-line mode.
[screenshot of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duc8K.png)

https://regex101.com/r/00gn0m/2

Do you have any suggestions to fix it on single-line mode?

Comment: Try `(\[ROB\d*])(?:\s*\n(?![A-Z]+\.\d+|\[ROB\d*]).*)*`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/0VSMfh/1). No `re.S`/`re.DOTALL` required here.

Comment: Thank you, Wiktor. This is not working as I want. It returns the line after the last line ending with a dot that shouldn't. The solution from @the-fourth-bird ( https://regex101.com/r/4s5jIk/1 ) working as expected.

Comment: I do not see where our solutions differ in output, but it is up to you, I just wanted to make sure you have an alternative solution. If you meant you need two groups per match, just use  a capturing group, as in `(\[ROB\d*])((?:\s*\n(?![A-Z]+\.\d+|\[ROB\d*]).*)*)`

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use single line mode because then the dot will match a newline and will match too much.

You can use a repeating inner non capture group inside the capture group.

Note that the match must end with a newline.

```
(\[ROB\d*])\s*\n\s*((?:.*[.:]\s*\n)*)
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3hQJcX/1)

```
(\[ROB\d*])[^\S\n]*((?:\n(?!\[ROB\d*]).*)*[.:](?=[^\S\n]*\n|$))
```

Another option could be matching `[ROB#]` followed by all lines that do not start with the same and match the last `.` or `:`

For example using re.findall

```
import re

pattern = r"(\[ROB\d*])[^\S\n]*((?:\n(?!\[ROB\d*]).*)*[.:](?=[^\S\n]*\n|$))"
s = ("A.82\n"
     "[ROB017] \n"
     "Lorem ipsum dolor ...")

print(re.findall(pattern, s))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2DlTMb/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/2h72Wl)

---

Using re.DOTALL you might use:

```
(\[ROB\d*])\s*\n(.*?[.:])[^:.]*(?=\n[A-Z]\.\d|$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4s5jIk/1)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I have to set the flag to DOTALL because of the string I have in my python app. Otherwise, the regex code matches nothing.

Comment: @Farsad How are you using the pattern? re.search or re.findall? How are you obtaining the string?

Comment: @Farsad See here how you could use re.findall https://ideone.com/2h72Wl

Comment: I get the string from a pdf reader package in pyhon. I use re.findall and re.finditer with the example code that regex101 makes.
I only managed to get it to work when the flag is set to DOTALL. on my jupyter notebook when I export the variable it get something like : "text \n text...". the `print(mystring)` print it on new lins. So, I think the string is fine. But I don't know why I should set the flag to single line to make it working.

Comment: @Farsad Can you add the result of `print(mystring)` to the question, and the relevant code that you are using?

Comment: @Farsad with the DOTALL set, you might use `(\[ROB\d*])\s*\n(.*?[.:])[^:.]*(?=\n[A-Z]\.\d|$)` https://regex101.com/r/4s5jIk/1

Comment: Thank you @the-fourth-bird. Your last solution working for me :) Could You post it as an answer? so, I could mark it as an accepted solution.

Comment: @Farsad This is an answer. Just click the grey tick on the left.